# React Native detect airplane mode

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

Is there a way to detect whether the airplane mode is turned on/off for React Native apps.

I found the [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-settings) to achieve this on Android but can't find a way to do the same on iOS.

If there's no way to do this via React Native is there a solution to write the code in Swift (which will get the Airplane mode settings) and plug it in React Native app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [react-native-system-settings](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting) is a library that can detect with conditions the airplane mode :

```
SystemSetting.isAirplaneEnabled().then((enable)=>{
  const state = enable ? 'On' : 'Off';
  console.log('Current airplane is ' + state);
})

SystemSetting.switchAirplane(()=>{
  console.log('switch airplane successfully');
})
```

But at this moment the

> isAirplaneEnabled() will always return true for iOS if your device has
>   no SIM card,

[see detail here](https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting/issues/37)